# Slide/move div's with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, slider

I'm quite new to jquery and didn't find any help on the following problem. Imagine this html code:

```
<div id="slideLeft">Click here to slide left</div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1">Content</div>
    <div id="div2">Content</div>
    <div id="div3">Content</div>
    <div id="div4">Content</div>
</div>
<div id="slideRight">Click here to slide right</div>
```

Every div has a fixed height and width, but the main div should only show two div's at once. On the left and on the right of this main div there are buttons or whatever (in this example just other divs) who slide the content div's when being clicked.

By default we would see div1, div2. When I click "slide right", it should move the div's so we would see div2, div3 after sliding. Etc etc.

I've seen many example with sliders (looking like scrollbars), but that's not really what I'm searching for.

Thanks for your input, I hope my question is clear enough!

Comment: this is a basic slider: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this a while ago (and have adapted it slightly for your needs). Working fiddle available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/CtNsE/2/

Comment: Answers should be fully self-contained and [talking about your experience is irrelevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128552).

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex and Ben. This is exactly what I meant, the idea of an inner div (with greater size than the outer div) is brilliant; I didn't come up with that idea.

Comment: Sorry at Ben again, I'm having troubles with the iPad. No kidding, this code works in iPhone 4S, IE (even compatibility mode), Safari, Chrome, FF. It doesn't work on the iPad... Do you have any idea what's the problem there?

Comment: At least the software update to iOS 5.1.1 fixed that and it is ok now... Weird bug though. ;)